# Hue does not work with https to connect Presto

Tags: sqlalchemy, presto, hue

the connection is closed when I try to access Hue by browser via https.
When I change https to http in the browser I can access, but after loging in, it gives the following error: *HTTPSConnectionPool(host='@myhost.mydomain', port=8443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/statement (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))*

I went to gethue.com and I have put the options with the same parameters as it is in the documentation *"Pass Trino Session properties along with HTTPS:"* in the configuration file options='{"url": "presto://username:password@myhost.mydomain:8443/system/runtime","connect_args":"{"protocol": "https", "session_props": {"query_max_run_time": "1m"}}"}'.

I was expecting to conncet presto and show the tables.

Does anyone have got this dificulty?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.